# Android's setImageBitmap changes width of ImageButton but must not

Tags: android

There is my button

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_weight="0.33" />
```

After calling setImageBitmap() on this, width is changing. How to set constant width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_weight="0.33" />
```

change it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, set the width to the fixed width you want: `android:layout_width="__width__"`

If you wanted it to be a third of the total width, set the width to 0.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:minWidth="200dp"
android:maxWidth="200dp"
```